# Form submition using AJAX is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im tring to submit form to other page using ajax, but it doesn't send the post.

Javascript on top of page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$(".button").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var dataVar = "name=" + name;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.example.ee/index.php?e=area_sa&date=2010",
        data: dataVar,
        success: function() {
            alert("works");
        }
    });
  });
});
<script>
```

And HTML code:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Add">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you're trying to make a cross-domain AJAX request.

If you have a domain **mywebsite.com**, then all AJAX requests should be limited to this domain, e.g. mywebsite.com/example/ajax/request.

What you're trying to do (cross-domain request) is possible but involves a workaround that's a bit more complicated, and makes use of different library calls.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that your click event is not bind to the .button,

That happen when the event is bind before the html element is loaded

few solutions :

1) encapsulate your JavaScript code inside an on-load event

2) place your JavaScript at the bottom of the page

3) use $(body).on('click', '.button' , function(){ /* your code here */})

also look like you posting to an external domain,
if you are the owner make sure you add the CORS policies.